# Getting Base URL With Angular 4

Tags: angular

Does anyone know how to get base url in Angular 4?
For example: think I have that -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
but I want to get only -> https://stackoverflow.com

I tried to get it like that :

```
constructor(private http: Http, private platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
            this.baseUrl = (platformLocation as any).location.origin;
    }
```

But I got that error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NodeInvocationException: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined
at new AppSettingsService (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:3028:50)
at _createClass (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20473:17)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20441:26)
at initNgModule (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20395:13)
at new NgModuleRef_ (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21503:9)
at Object.createNgModuleRef (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21487:12)
at NgModuleFactory_.module.exports.NgModuleFactory_.create (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:24768:25)
at D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:15453:61
at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invoke (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85786:26)
at Object.onInvoke (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:14830:37)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 2):

if you only want to get the origin of any path, you can just use
window.location in ngOnInit instead of the constructor

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.baseUrl = window.location.origin
}
```

Comment: I used it actually but I got an error when I press F5. Is tere any other way?

Comment: Which browser are you using? IE may have a problem with that function.. anyway, Replace the `(platformLocation as any).location.origin` with `window.location.origin` and tell me what browser you are using.

Comment: I am using chrome latest version.

Comment: After changing it, I got also "window is not defined" error.

Comment: You are trying to use this in client side right? Not the nodejs server right?

Comment: Yes, it is the client side. Actually, I am trying to call a initialize web service to get some settings. But when I tried this I got an error about using the absolute path.  I was using http.get("/api/settings").map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .toPromise()
            .then((data: any) => this.endpointUrl = data.serviceEndPoint)
            .catch((err: any) => Promise.resolve()); So, to solve that problem I need full path.

Comment: Try defining what you wanted to do not in the constructor but in ngOnInit like this: `ngOnInit() { this.baseUrl = window.location.origin }`

Comment: I did as you said but it is giving me empty string :(

Comment: Can you post the component?

Comment: @Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService implements OnInit {public endpointUrl: string;public baseUrl: string;constructor(private http: Http) {}
    ngOnInit() { this.baseUrl = window.location.origin }
    load(): Promise<any> { var settingUrl = this.baseUrl + "/api/setting/GetServiceEndpoint";
        return this.http.get(settingUrl).map((res: Response) => res.json())           .toPromise().then((data: any) => this.endpointUrl = data.serviceEndPoint)
            .catch((err: any) => Promise.resolve());}
    public GetServiceEndpoint(): string {return this.endpointUrl;}
}

Comment: and this is where  I called it:  providers: [
        SettingVaultService,
        PaymentLocationService,
        AppSettingsService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
            deps: [AppSettingsService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]

Comment: Instead of using baseurl, try removing ngoninit at all, and replace in the load() function the `this.baseUrl` with `window.location.origin` EDIT: just noticed its a service.. it shouldnt have ngoninit because its not a component

Comment: in the app.module.ts

Comment: I did for this time again I got "window is not defined". I am going to be crazy :( I hate angular :)

Comment: If you have email, I can send app.module and this component, maybe you can see the problem

Comment: Can you post the service again? And the component that is calling the service? If there is one